# EMR cluster stuck on resizing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have an EMR Cluster that I created back in April 2020 with 1 master(on-demand), 1 core (spot) and multiple Task nodes (spot). I have been using it actively and things had been going well until last few days ago. For some reason, the cluster has gone into "Waiting" mode as it is trying to find spot instances for the Core node. I have the provisioning set as "After 300 minutes, shift to on-demand instances). I see the status "resizing" for Core node.

I don't know what to do next. I am on Basic Support with AWS. I would really like not to terminate this cluster and rebuild it as I spent a lot of time putting my personal configuration touches on it. What could I have done better to prevent this in the future?

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming Q&A site, so this question is likely to be closed. You haven't really provided enough information for somebody to identify a cause for the issue you are experiencing. You should probably enrol for AWS Support and request their assistance. You can always turn off Support afterwards (but it is normally worth having!).

Comment: Thanks. Wish I knew why the cluster went in Resizing mode without me doing anything. But I wll take your advise.

Answer (score 0):

The Resizing of EMR Cluster have lots of issues. It is not advisable to have all spot instance from single box. I would suggest few work arounds.

0. STOP the resizing. Wait to see the changes . Read error message. Then again issue Resizing request.
1. If you don't use HDFS (say do everything from S3) , kill the Cluster and get a new one.

If you are using that, I suggest you go through https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-resizing-and-automatic-scaling-in-amazon-emr/ .

2. When creating cluster which requires only spot,use 2 or 3 box-
   a. 10% On-Demand Value - 1 instance
   b. 20% On-Demand Value - 1 instance

I suggest you keep 1 on-demand if budget permits, and then try.